# prove $a_{ii}a_{jj}>|a_{ij}|^2$ for a complex positive definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Show that if an $n*n$ complex matrix $[a_{ij}]$ is positive definite then $a_{ii}a_{jj}>|a_{ij}|^2$ for all distinct $i$ and $j$ such that $i,j=1,...,n$.

The last part of question was the same for $n=2$. I did that using a determinant argument but I cannot use the same idea in general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $M = \pmatrix{a_{ii}&a_{ij}\\a_{ji}& a_{jj}}$ is a [principal submatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Submatrix) of $A$. Thus, if $A$ is positive definite, then so is $M$.

Comment: I don't see how this is a principal submatrix, if we're using the same definition of one.

Comment: @cmk we remove all rows and columns of $A$ except the $i$th and $j$th to produce $M$

Comment: I see, I'm just used to a different definition.